# Stream Sorted, Reversed Absolute Value based on , implementing Comparator or ToIntFunction, Java 8

Tags: sorting, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I was sorting with

```
someList.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(someClass::getValue).reversed())
```

Now, I need to sorting by Absolute Value like this answer: [`abs_number = (number < 0) ? -number : number;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11013211/811293)  (Not using <s>`Math.abs(x)` or `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2))`</s>)

**How implement a new `java.util.Comparator` or `java.util.function.ToIntFunction` in order by AbsoluteValue in reverse Order?**

Comment: Why not use `abs`? The straight-forward solution is `someList.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(v -> Math.abs(v.getValue())).reversed());`, but if you insist on not using `abs`, then just use `someList.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(v -> v.getValue() < 0? -v.getValue(): v.getValue())).reversed());`

Comment: The same method in implementation of abs in http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java and here https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29964108/811293):

```
someList
.sorted((a, b) -> 
    Integer.valueOf(b.getValue() < 0 ? -b.getValue() : b.getValue())
    .compareTo(a.getValue() < 0 ? -a.getValue() : a.getValue())
)
```

According to [implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java) of `Math.abs(x)` is the same code that you are requiring.

```
someList
.sorted((a, b) ->
    Integer.valueOf(Math.abs(b.getValue()))
    .compareTo(Math.abs(a.getValue()))
)
```

Alternatively

```
someList
.sorted(Comparator.<SomeClass>comparingInt(s -> Math.abs(s.getValue())).reversed())
```